# Death of Hazrat Bibi Aminah(r.a)

Tags: history

How the death of Hazrat Bibi Aminah(r.a) had been occured and where did she burried?

Comment: Who is Bubi Amnah?

Comment: Bibi Amnah was the mother of the Islamic prophet Muhammad(P.B.U.H)

Comment: Then her name is [Aminah](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aminah). Have in mind that many terms are rather used locally for us Arabic speakers "bibi" makes no sense.

Comment: Aminah wife of abdullah died as kaafir, she is a resident of hell as per sahih hadith. No need to use r.a

Comment: Please research the terms before writing a question. Most of your questions use Urdu terms that are confusing for the readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amina (RA) died while returning from a journey to Yathrib. Her grave is in Al-Abwa'.

Answer (score 0):

Both the mother and father of the holy prophet were the followers of hazrat ibrahim A.S.
As per one saying, hazrat Bibi Aminah R.A  was returning after offering fateha (Prayers) at the grave of her husband  Hazrat Abdullah R.A.(Father of holy prophet). She is now buried in Al-Abwa, which is almost at a center point between Mecca and Medina.

Comment: Reference(s) from Qur'an, Hadith, and other acceptable Islamic sources are recommended.